# routes in rails - removing actions when setting up a resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I've setup a simple app and added a scaffold to do some of the work for me (I'm a noob).

```
  resources :cars
```

How do I remove certain actions from the routes? And remove the corresponding urls?

For example I want to keep the 'show' and 'edit' actions & urls.

But I don't want there to be a 'new' 'index' or 'delete'

I understand this is probably a really simple question, but I've not been able to find an answer.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

```
resources :cars, :except => [:new, :index, :delete]
```

or

```
resources :cars, :only => [:show, :edit]
```

Also take a look at [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#restricting-the-routes-created)

Comment: is it possible to set this in `cars` controller?

Answer (score 1):

```
If you want to remove some actions then you can mention action name in the array

resources :photos, only: [:index, :show]
```

But

```
if you want to disable all the default CRUD actions then you should use
    
resources :photos, only: []
```