# Rails: How to suppress the generation of certain routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I have this route in my routes.rb

```
resource: session
```

It generates the following routes

```
session_path    POST    /session(.:format)  sessions#create
new_session_path    GET     /session/new(.:format)  sessions#new
edit_session_path   GET     /session/edit(.:format)     sessions#edit
```

I do not require edit_session_path (at least I don't know yet whether I require it or not) and I have a custom route for signin, so I don't want new_session_path.

Is there a way to tell Rails to not generate these two paths?

Answer (score 2):

```
resources :sessions, :except => [:new, :edit]
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, if you know which actions you want you can provide it directly via `only`, instead of excepting them:

```
resources :sessions, only: [:create]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need more than 1 resource to configure

```
with_options(except: [:new, :edit]) do |opt|
  opt.resource :session
  opt.resource :another_resource
  opt.resources :people
end
```

like in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26616053/default-exclude-option-for-rails-resource-routing)

or like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8258392/routes-in-rails-removing-actions-when-setting-up-a-resource) - similar to the upper answer.